# Ошибка установки Windows

Tags: windows, установка

Windows 7 глючила, по этому решил почистить (внутри) комп, переустановить винду, если не поможет, везти в ремонт. В чем суть глюка: при нагрузке компьютер вис намертво, раньше в играх лагали текстуры, но потом стало хуже. В общем, закончилась установка (c usb), последний этап, и вот загрузился windows 7 и пишет:

> Компьютер неожиданно перезагрузился или возникла непредвиденая ошибка.

Жму ок.

> Установка будет продолжена после перезагрузки.

Но после перезагрузки опять пишет ошибку, опять жму ок, и так по кругу! В безопасном режиме зависает на

> Программа загружает службы

Что же делать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас аппаратная проблема, возможно память барахлит и, как следствие, вылетает в самых неожиданных местах. Но может быть и любая другая аппаратная проблема. Выньте все лишние платы, оставьте только одну планку памяти (если есть другая на 100% рабочя, то вставьте ее, а остальные выньте). Если будет работать, то постепенно (по одной) вставляйте ваши платы и каждый раз прогоняйте тесты. Так можно будет определить виновника глюков.

Или несите комп в ремонт, если не сможете определить проблему.

Comment: Наверное, понесу в ремонт.) Я-то с компом дружу... но стремно запороть его будет. )

Comment: А чего стремного-то?
Комплект мать+проц+память стоит в пределах 5000 руб., что не такие уж громадные деньги. А остальное можно со старого компьютера содрать.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вначале установить заново, только возьмите другой дистрибутив, ваш может быть битый, проверьте его контрольную сумму, попробуйте устанавливать не с флешки, а с диска.

Comment: При установке с диска пишет что нету дров. И как установить снова? Ведь если я опять поставлю загрузку флехи (в биосе) 1, то выдаст ошибку и напишет мол нажмите контр альт дел.

Comment: что именно пишет? какие дрова?

Comment: сдрома дров нету.

Comment: а,как это нет дров на CD-ROM?

Answer (score 0):

1. нужно написать полную конфигурацию ПК. Потом будем думать.
2. Берем любой дистрибутив Линукса, качаем, пишем на болванку и там есть стресс-тесты. Например, memtest86+ для памяти. Гоним по кругу.
3. Если есть возможность переключиться на встроенную видеокарту, вынув внешнюю - это было б супер.
4. На всякий случай можно сбросить настройки BIOS с помощью джампера Clear CMOS. В чудо не верю, но мало ли...

Answer (score 0):

1. Пере установите заново - может поможет.
2. Не помогло - возьмите у друга другую Винду (может у Вас Винда просто барыжная).
3. Проверьте Вios.
4. Не помогло - ну тут только ремонт,я думаю проблемы с жестянкой...